# How to rename tag [urbanairship.com]: [airship] or [airship.com]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

On 17th of April 2019, Urban Airship became **Airship**: https://twitter.com/airship/status/1118516412379611136. Their new address is simply https://www.airship.com.

How to rename the existing tag [urbanairship.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urbanairship.com)? My first idea was [airship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airship), but then I feared it would be an ambiguous tag, considering it's also [a common word in the dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/airship). So maybe [airship.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airship.com)?

What do you think?

Comment: `airship.com` would be the logical choice, it seems.